# Position absolute for button to achieve responsive

Tags: html, css

Imagine this is my header http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2013/01/banner-2.jpg, and the button have to be clickable. I don't want to slice the images and put it into blocks. How can the button be clickable and achieved responsive in the same time??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to be so complacent as this can simply be done via Pure CSS only where you can put your image as a background an create this button via CSS and make it clickable.

But, like you have mentioned you do not want to go this way, the only way would be to create another image for a responsive layout and on that image, you need to show/hide based on your requirements and assign a class that changes the click position to match it as per your new image button using image map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when the browser get resize the position of the button is fixed anymore.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you have to use separate media queries for this to work.

Comment: Nope .. The best is the one I have mentioned above. Just save your image without the button and create the button via CSS.

Comment: I know but it's not perfect, the image size will scale, the button if it's position absoulte it doesn't go up.

Comment: For that, like I mentioned above, you need to use Media Queries.